# Dynamically add a function to a python module (instead of a class)?

Tags: python

I'm aware I can add it to a particular class or its instance using the `setattr` method. But in my case I want to dynamically "add" it to say a utilities.py module in a way that every file that does 'import utilities' sees this new function.

Comment: So what's wrong with the `setattr` approach?

Comment: What's wrong with using your $EDITOR

Comment: @Rawing I believe `setattr` needs the first input to be a class name. In this case utilities.py has no class definitions.. it's just a module containing helper functions.

Comment: Believing means you didn't [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) nor try it out. `setattr` works with any object.

Comment: You can do `import utilities; utilities.new_func = ...` in a module (let's call it `monkeypatch.py`.  Then, if you `import monkeypatch` in addition to `import utilities` in a python file, you will have `utilities.new_func` available.

Answer (score 0):

let's call your "new function" `new_func()`. I'm not quite sure which of the following you mean:

- `import utilities` will make `utilities.new_func()` available

OR

- `import utilities` will make `new_func()` available without the `utilities` prefix.

#### If it's the former:

Just put the function inside the module somewhere in that module's top-level namespace. In other words `def new_func()` should not be indented **at all**.

#### If it's the latter:

You are out of luck; you'll need to change `import utilities` to `from utilities import *` which is not recommended and would be just as much work as explicitly importing `new_func()`.

Comment: Neither: I wanted to dynamically add a function - not define it in the source file. @Rawing's comment solved my issue.